# Data Validation - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is the code that I have edited so far for the upcoming AS computing Preliminary code.
It's homework and I am stuck as to why it does not work.  Any suggestions? Thanks

```
def GetKeyForCaesarCipher():  
  while True:
    key = int(raw_input('Enter the amount that shifts the plaintext alphabet to the ciphertext alphabet: '))
    try:
      i = int(key)
      break
    except ValueError:
      print 'please enter an interger'
    return (key)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: If the OP had articulated the symptom, he would have spotted the actual problem.

Comment: Why do you ask two times? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275360/python-2-7-data-validation Or was that a friend?

Comment: I have found the problem so thanks for the help anyway.  and to Jan-Philip, there are other people in the world on python?

Answer (score 3):

you should just do `key = raw_input(...)` rather than `key = int(raw_input(...))`

With the former, `key` is a string until you `try` to make it an integer.  With the latter, you attempt to construct an `int` from it right away without guarding that attempt with any exception handling.

---

There are some other logic flaws as well.  Right now, your infinite `while` loop doesn't do anything for example.  (you return after the first pass no matter what).  Moving the `return` statment where the `break` is would probably* make it do what you want.  Also, you don't do anything with the `int` that you construct (`i`), although it's unclear whether or not you *should* be returning it or `key`.

*I'm making assumptions about what your program is supposed to do here...