# Python 2.7 data validation

Tags: python, validation

I need help for this data validation problem in Python 2.7, it does what i want it doesn't accept strings however it doesn't accept integers either as it should do.

```
def GetKeyForCaesarCipher():
  while True:
    key =(raw_input('Enter the amount that shifts the plaintext alphabet to the ciphertext alphabet: '))
    try:
      i=int(key)
      break
    except ValueError:
      print ('Error, please enter an integer')

  return key
```

Comment: "What do you mean by does not work" is a constructive question around here.  We need to know what the code is supposed to do, and what it is actually doing to correctly diagnose your problem.  Below, Martijn is assuming that you want to return integers from the function, but there is no way in this post to know whether that (reasonable) assumption is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It accepts integers just fine, but you are returning the original string value. You should either return `i` or assign to `key` instead:

```
key = int(key)
```

Comment: Hey, how'd you get 4 upvotes on this when I only got 2 [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15275111/748858).  Ninja skills?

Comment: @mgilson almost even now.

Comment: @vikki -- It's not actually a problem.  I'm just messing with Martijn.  And lets face it.  If Martijn answers a question around here, that's an automatic +3 for him.

Comment: Subtract the automatic +3 and I'm still ahead (currently)! :-P

Comment: @mgilson haha I know, I just noticed I hadn't upvoted anything today.

Answer (score 0):

Martijn's answer is correct, of course, but if you improved your *style*, you might find debugging easier.  Try it like this:

```
def promptForInteger(prompt):
  while True:
    try:
      return int(raw_input(prompt))
    except ValueError:
      print ('Error, please enter an integer')

def getKeyForCaesarCipher():
   return promptForInteger('Enter the amount that shifts the plaintext alphabet to the ciphertext alphabet: ')
```